# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 7 y sizes: 8

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I can't solve the problem. This is my error message:

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 7
y sizes: 8
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SzyU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivHdo.png)

Answer (score 0):

kilometer have 7 elements and mil have 8 elements

But you need to have the same number of elements

Comment: Thanks for help me. My homework is very busy so I couldn't notice